# How to move from IV7 to V in keyboard style without parallels?

Tags: voice-leading

I tried and this is the best that I could come up with. There is a rather big leap between IV7 and V and I was not able to resolve the dissonance :( Is there a solution? The question says ^3 must be in the soprano for IV7. The chords are required to be in root position, and the solution is to be given in keyboard style.

[image: Attempt at moving from IV7 to V in keyboard style]

Comment: Does the book require that both chords be 1) in root position and 2) complete?

Comment: Yes, in this case they must be in root position.

Comment: And must they also be complete?

Comment: Can they be complete? would leaving them incomplete be a more preferable solution?

Comment: The chorale style example in the book has complete chords with a large alto leap... however the example uses chorale style and mine is keyboard style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you picked E♯ in the soprano for the V chord, especially since you now have crossed voices with that soprano note and the *alto* F♯ note in the IV7 chord. Even if voices didn't get crossed, A♯-E♯ sounds more than a touch awkward in the melody, especially this near what sounds like a cadence.

Assuming the soprano isn't completely unchangeable, I'd recommend changing it first.

(Assume all solutions from here on are SATB from top to bottom.)

If we're going for a nice soprano line, we're likely stuck with an awkward leap in an inner voice. I think this is OK as long as you like tripling the root shortly afterwards in the I chord or sounding like an imperfect authentic cadence:

A♯-G♯(-A♯ or F♯)

D♯-E♯(-F♯)

F♯-C♯(-C♯ or A♯)

B-C♯(-F♯)

Alternately, these use a smoother interval of a third in the soprano in IV7-V, even if the chordal 7th might not resolve how you think it would:

A♯-C♯(-C♯)

F♯-E♯(-F♯)

D♯-G♯(-A♯)

B-C♯(-F♯)

---

A♯-C♯(-A♯)

F♯-E♯(-F♯)

D♯-C♯(-C♯)

B-C♯(-F♯)

Answer (score 1):

## Moving from IV7 to V with ^3 in the soprano

#### Complete chords

This is not possible without parallels. The core problem is that the IV7 chord contains two perfect fifths.

The bass ^4 must move to ^5, and the soprano ^3 must move to ^2. This leaves the following possibilities:

- ^6 moves to ^5: creates a parallel fifth with ^3 moving to ^2.
- ^1 moves to ^2: creates a parallel fifth with ^4 moving to ^5.
- ^6 and ^1 both move to ^7: creates a doubles leading tone.

#### Incomplete chords

**Omitting the fifth (^1) from the IV7 chord**

The problems with ^1 are that it either creates a parallel fifth with ^4 or a doubled leading tone, shown above. By leaving it out, ^6 can move to ^7.

Since the texture is four-voice, my feeling is the best solution is to double the root of the IV7 chord (i.e., the "tenor" voice doubles the bass) and have it move to the fifth of the V chord; in other words, ^4 moves to ^2. This creates a hidden octave between the "tenor" and "soprano" voices, but other solutions creates parallel fifths, which are far more clearly audible.

Comment: For the complete chords and ^3 to ^2 version, why can't ^6 move to ^7 and ^1 move to ^5 like in my answer?

Comment: @Dekkadeci I was focused on smooth voice-leading without leaps. I read the question to mean leaps should be avoided, but subsequent comments suggest they're okay.

Comment: @Dekkadeci In keyboard style, ^1 to ^5 would be problematic only in that it introduces a voice crossing. OP would have to clarify whether or not that's permitted.

Comment: What is keyboard style, then? Do the top 3 voices all have to be played in the right hand? I'd have thought that keyboard style just means that it's playable by one person and their two hands on a keyboard (which means that even my answer needs no voice crossing as long as the left hand can play 2 notes in the IV7 chord).

Comment: @Dekkadeci Keyboard style usually means the upper 3 voices are within an octave — at least in the context of the kind of book OP is learning from. So, yes, playable by right hand, but even a bit more restrictive.

Comment: Aaron, when you say omit ^1 do you mean have a 3 voice chord or double one of the other notes?

Comment: @armani Good catch. I was thinking in 3 voices without realizing. I've updated to address four voices.

Comment: Aaron, and I suppose all these problems are because this is in keyboard style right? If we were to start over in chorale style we would have many more options with those same soprano voices and not be so limited. This seriously makes me consider how much more options you have in a chorale style exercise. I hadnt figured it would be such a big difference.

Comment: @armani Not necessarily. This answer's description of how the voices move and the problems that occur are not dependent on the style. They are true in both chorale and keyboard voicings.

Comment: Look here.  https://ibb.co/hczc6NX I cant see how you can say that, the solution in chorale style is much smoother. Only one inner voice leap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130584/discussion-between-aaron-and-armani).

Answer (score 0):

Can the V be a V7?   Seems reasonable, as it's preceded by a nice juicy Maj7 chord.   In fact, it would sound rather bare without!  In block chord style rather than part-writing I think we can allow the falling leading note.  (Actually, I think I'd do it even in SATB, unless you really wanted the melody line to duck down to it on the penultimate chord.)

[image]

Comment: No. It must be V. I think it is to try teach us the difficulties in the voice leading and how to overcome them. The example in my book I posted in my last comment to Aaron show  a good solution but I chose to use block chords thinking I could get similar results. Had I done the exercise in chorale style I could have just used the voice leading in the example with the leap in the alto.

Comment: OK.    You disobeyed the rule by not writing in 4 parts.   No problem, rules are made to be broken!  Another bit of disobedience - using V7 instead of plain V - would have made it work.  So break two rules!

Comment: Yeah I know. Another example in my book avoids parallels by using V7. Did I disobey the rule? isnt keyboard style also 4 parts?